# Which mysql tables contain the URL Alias path data?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Im looking to manually change a node's URL path as my edit button throws me an error upon clicking it since this was due to orphaned data left over from some other uninstalled modules. Which tables contain the URL alias path data in Drupal 7?

Comment: 1000+ views deserves an upvote

Comment: since drupal 8.8 the url_alias table no longer exists, it has been replaced by the path_alias table

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Table i was looking for was **url_alias**

[image]