# Where in the MySQL database schema is the URL alias for a group relation?

Tags: 8, database, path-aliases, group

I am building a report outside of Drupal that pulls data from a Drupal 8 database.  The report shows titles of different nodes and I want to link those titles to the web page for that content.  This is working fine if I use the standard /node/X path, but I would like to use the URL alias.  I don't want the url alias of the node itself (which I did find thanks to this [Which mysql tables contain the URL Alias path data?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76435/which-mysql-tables-contain-the-url-alias-path-data) post).  Our content is related to groups, so I want to use the URL alias that is created as part of the group entity relation.

[image]

At first I checked the url_alias table, using this query to look for the node id in the source field, but I didn't find the alias set up for that node :

```
select u.alias 
from url_alias u
where u.source LIKE '%4806%'
```

Then I tried to check the group tables.  I only find 5 tables starting with group in the MySQL schema, and I didn't find the URL alias for the entity reference in any of them:

- group_content
- group_content__group_roles
- group_content_field_data
- groups
- groups_field_data

Does anyone know where that URL alias from the group relation is stored in the MySQL schema?

Comment: All URL aliases that use the core system are in the `url_alias` table. It's not just for nodes. From the screenshot it looks like whatever entity type that is uses the core alias system (the checkbox is a giveaway), so you should find its aliases in the same table

Comment: Thanks Clive, I've edited my answer above to show that I thought I tried that.  But now I realize that the group aliases do not have the node id in the source field, so that's why my query didn't work.  Querying url_alias table looking for the known alias in the alias field, I was able to find it now.  If you want to write your comment as an answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As Clive stated in the comment, all aliases are in the url_alias table.

You should join it with the og_membership table, to take the url alias of the node's group.

So, for a node with id 100, the script should look like:

```
select u.alias 
from og_membership og, url_alias u
where concat('node/', og.gid) = u.source
and og.etid = 100 and og.group_type like 'node'
```

Comment: This structure is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Maria.  Sorry that I forgot to mention the version.  I am using Drupal 8, and I don't see an og_membership table.  I've edited the question to mention the version.

Answer (score 0):

url_alias is path_alias in drupal 8

```
select n.nid, n.vid, n.type, pa.path, pa.alias, pa.status
from node n 
inner join path_alias pa on pa.path = concat('/node/', n.nid);
```